# twilio tutorial problems

Tags: java, twilio

i followed the tutorial at https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/java/twiml/record-caller-leave-message and am getting stuck at the recording. the twilio logs indicate "Problem accessing /handle-key. with a 404." i am set up with localtunnel, and i configured my number to point to the http://43v8.localtunnel.com/myapp/twilio url. the greeting works, i only have trouble when picking 1 or 2 on my dial pad. i would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

TwilioHandleRecordingServlet:

```
package com.twilio;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;

import com.twilio.sdk.verbs.TwiMLResponse;
import com.twilio.sdk.verbs.TwiMLException;
import com.twilio.sdk.verbs.Say;
import com.twilio.sdk.verbs.Play;
import com.twilio.sdk.verbs.Dial;

public class TwilioHandleRecordingServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

        String recordingUrl = request.getParameter("RecordingUrl");
        TwiMLResponse twiml = new TwiMLResponse();
        if (recordingUrl != null) {
            try {
                twiml.append(new Say("Thanks for howling... take a listen to what you howled."));
                twiml.append(new Play(recordingUrl));
                twiml.append(new Say("Goodbye"));
            } catch (TwiMLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            response.sendRedirect("/twiml");
            return;
        }

        response.setContentType("application/xml");
        response.getWriter().print(twiml.toXML());
    }
}
```